# How to create a json array inside an array without nested loops?

Tags: plsql

I need to find companies that have at least 1 sold out product, and return them in a json of this structure:

```
[{
  "companyName": "Company A",
  "soldOutProducts": [{"productName": "Product A"}, {"product Name": "Product B"}]
},
{
  "companyName": "Company B",
  "soldOutProducts": [{"productName": "Product 1"}, {"product Name": "Product 2"}]
},
{
  "companyName": "Company C",
  "soldOutProducts": [{"productName": "Product $$"}, {"product Name": "Product @@"}]
}]
```

Currently I have a nested loop:

```
for v_company (select id
               from v_companies
               where district_id = v_district_id) loop

  for v_product (select id
                 from v_products
                 where company_id = v_company.id
                 and sold_out = 1) loop

  --if a product is found, it is added to the product json list here

  end loop;

  --if product list has at least 1 element, then a new object is created in the main json list,
  --in which the company name is saved
  --and a list of proudcts added
end loop;
```

Both selects are more complicated in reality (both involve several joins), plus there are thousands of companies to scan.

Is there a more efficient way how to create such json, i.e., how to add only companies that have at least 1 sold out product plus the sold out product list?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a 2step transformation:

1. Apply the BASIC SQL rule: 1 query always beats 2 loops. So join your
   queries.
2. Apply [SQL/JSON](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/generation.html#GUID-6C3441E8-4F02-4E95-969C-BBCA6BDBBD9A) functions to that result.

These steps can be accomplished in a single query.

```
with v_company( id, district_id) as
     (select 1, 1 from dual union all
      select 1, 2 from dual union all
      select 2, 1 from dual union all 
      select 3, 2 from dual union all      
      select 4, 2 from dual
     )
   , v_product (id, company_id, sold_out) as 
     (select 196,3,1 from dual union all
      select 168,2,1 from dual union all
      select 157,3,0 from dual union all
      select 164,1,0 from dual union all
      select 124,3,0 from dual union all
      select 187,1,1 from dual  
     )
select json_object( 'company'  value  c.id  
                  , 'district' value  c.district_id 
                  , 'product'  value  p.id  
                  ) 
  from v_product p
  join v_company c
    on (p.company_id = c.id)
 where 1=1
   and p.sold_out = 1
   and c.district_id = 1
;
```

See [example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=aea778b267b1a69fb8f35c4e5c0355d8) and SQL/JSON for additional JSON functions and formats.

Answer (score 0):

If you have APEX installed you can try the `apex_json.write(refcursor)` procedure. Something like this should get you started:

```
DECLARE
  curs sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
  open curs for 
    select Company_name as "companyName",
      cursor ( 
        select PRODUCT_NAME as "productName" 
        from v_products vp
        where vp.company_id = vc.id
          and sold_out = 1
      ) as "soldOutProducts"
    from v_companies vc
    where district_id = v_district_id;
    
  apex_json.initialize_clob_output;

  apex_json.write(curs); -- 

  dbms_output.put_line(apex_json.get_clob_output);

  apex_json.free_output;
END;
/
```